# How to asses the accuracy of past predicted chances

Tags: probability, prediction, accuracy, games

I'm trying to asses how accurate [FiveThirtyEight's NBA predictions](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2017-nba-predictions/?ex_cid=rrpromo) were for the Pistons. They give a percentage chance for a team to win for every game. I wanted to test that against the actual outcome and see how accurate they've been overall for the Pistons.

This is probably a really basic question, but it's been a while and I haven't been able to find anything on Google or SE. I'm not looking for anything too complicated, but if this is a deeper problem, I'm willing to read up on it if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The reason why I'm interested is that I don't know anything about basketball, but I generally trust FiveThirtyEight and I made a lot of bets with my bros based on their predictions. Some of those are still giving me better chances, but sometimes I feel like my bros' traditional knowledge turns out to be more accurate than FTE's predictions

Comment: I think you may be looking for scoring rules like Brier score. There is a tag for it and some threads you can browse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @mdewey said in the comments, sounds like you're looking for [scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule). In particular, you presumably want a proper scoring rule such as the Brier score (i.e., mean squared error from probabilities to outcomes) or logarithmic score (i.e., the logarithm of the predicted probability for the obtained outcome).